# How do I setup MAC spoofing in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, mac-address, spoofing

I would like to setup MAC spoofing in Fedora, similar do what Tails does to their Debian.
Any idea how?
Thanks

Comment: This is distribution-independent. Most modern network cards can be configured to change their MAC address.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ip` tool to spoof your MAC address. Here is an example for `eth0`:

```
ip link set dev eth0 down
ip link set dev eth0 address 01:01:01:01:01:01
ip link set dev eth0 up
```

Source: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing

Answer (score 3):

For a permanent change, nmcli can be used it change it in Network Manager. That way, your change would be permanent.

```
nmcli connection down eth0
nmcli connection modify eth0 802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address 01:01:01:01:01:01
nmcli connection up eth0
```

It can be used for wifi as well, also per connection! Just note for wifi is different connection type, 802-11-wireless.cloned-mac-address would be correct variable. If supported, it is always value of connection.type followed by cloned-mac-address.